# How to type a function that checks if argument extends type argument and returns the argument in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to type a function that checks that it's argument's type extends a type variable, and then returns the argument.
Like this:

```
declare function extendsA<I, X extends I>(argument:X): X
```

But when I use it, typescript complains that the function takes two type arguments.
Or this:

```
declare function extendsB<I, X extends I = I>(argument:X): X
```

And that returns the wrong type.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXxAA8MRVgBnAQQB4BJAGngA0DjSL5aA+AClgHNkAW1IYAXEwCUY5gFgAUAoVESZKtQBEACSwaAPtpAQIODb0PHTkpfNCRYCFOmx5WqigCE6jFivblOeABeTl4BYVEJaTlFWLA8cgx4AHcYPH4AFQBPAAcEEL81L21dAy0jEzMeC0rJeAB6esDkqFQkmtN4KACMAAsEOAxkGHwMXIRUHHadDXg9eA6NIA)

How do I make typescript take the type of `argument` put it into the type variable `X`, ensure that it extends `I` and then return `X`?

A use case would be:

```
const recordOfNumberArray = extendsA<{[K: string]: readonly number[]}>({
"hello":[10,200]
} as const); // good
recordOfNumberArray. // with intellisense of all keys
```

```
const recordOfNumberArray = extendsA<{[K: string]: readonly number[]}>({
"hello":[10,200,"hi"]
} as const); // should error
```

Comment: I don't follow - why are there two generics here? Presumably the caller knows what is passed in - why exactly would the caller have to specify what type is passed in and what it extends? Why would it matter?

Comment: @VLAZ I edited the post to include a use case, I'm looking to make a "compiler macro", the function call should be removed when compiling and replaced with just the value.

Comment: @jackssrt So this function should constrain its argument to some supertype, and infer a more specific subtype?

Comment: That's a bad example; `readonly [10, 200]` does not extends `number[]` so your "correct" `recordOfNumberArray` would cause an error.  Could you try again?  Perhaps `{[K: string]: readonly number[]}`?

Comment: Due to the lack of partial inference of generic parameters, the closest I can get is this: https://tsplay.dev/Wk5LLN which breaks the generics apart with nested functions. Not exactly an elegant or intuitive interface, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, you're trying to implement the so-called "`satisfies`" operator, as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#7481](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7481).  The idea there is that you could write `val satisfies Type`, and there'd be a compiler error if `val` is not of type `Type`, but it does not *widen* `val` to type `Type`.  Unfortunately such an operator does not yet exist in TypeScript, so you are resorting to a workaround.  I'm going to rename `extendsA` to `satisfies` from here on.

---

So you can't easily implement `satisfies` as a single [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function of two type parameters, since TypeScript also lacks *partial type parameter inference* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242).  Either the compiler will infer all type parameters from the call, or you have to manually specify all the type parameters.  As you discovered, a [generic type parameter default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) cannot be used to give you partial inference, since all you'll get is the default if you leave out the parameter.

Instead, the normal way around this is to refactor to a [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) function, where the function takes only the generic type parameter to be manually specified, and then it returns another function which takes the type parameter to be inferred.  Like this:

```
// declare function satisfies<I>(): <X extends I>(argument: X) => X;

function satisfies<I>() {
    return <X extends I>(argument: X) => argument
}
```

And therefore you have to call it like this, with an extra function call step:

```
satisfies<{ [K: string]: readonly number[] }>()({
    "hello": [10, 200]
} as const); // good
```

It's not wonderful, although the pain can be lessened if you find yourself checking for the same `I` type more than once, since you can reuse the partially applied function:

```
const satisfiesRecordOfNumberArray =
    satisfies<{ [K: string]: readonly number[] }>();    

const recordOfNumberArray = satisfiesRecordOfNumberArray({
    "hello": [10, 200]
} as const); // good
recordOfNumberArray.hello // okay    

const recordOfNumberArray2 = satisfiesRecordOfNumberArray({
    "hello": [10, 200, "hi"]
} as const); // error! 
// Type 'readonly [10, 200, "hi"]' is not assignable to type 'readonly number[]'
```

---

The only other approach I can think of is to keep the two type parameters in one function, `I` and `X`, but add a dummy function parameter `dummyI` of type `I`.  This is probably even worse than currying, since it forces you to provide a dummy value of type `I`, or pretend to:

```
// declare function satisfies<I, X extends I>(dummyI: I, argument: X): X;
function satisfies<I, X extends I>(dummyI: I, argument: X) { return argument }

const recordOfNumberArray = satisfies(null! as { [K: string]: readonly number[] }, {
    "hello": [10, 200]
} as const); // good

const recordOfNumberArray2 = satisfies(null! as { [K: string]: readonly number[] }, {
    "hello": [10, 200, "hi"]
} as const); // error! 
// Type 'readonly [10, 200, "hi"]' is not assignable to type 'readonly number[]'
```

That works, but now instead of `satisfies<I>()(val)` you have `satisfies(null! as I, val)`.  As I said, probably worse, although it's subjective.  Ideally you wouldn't need any function calls and there'd be a built-in `satisfies` operator.  Without a built-in operator, the jump from one function call to two function calls doesn't seem much worse than the jump from zero to one.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-JoOJpdN3DH2TMaSIOF5p3GOvJPp7P54vEDJQooV6Ako5nMQl2EmmrjpqRTrcVSAMyG7cDswVT9CGnJ3ik6SkCCuQFOikJJtCTYIlM1p0jKjLDCyTrsp6YE+jgPJbPy+w6Ph6JmliFoSgALP+pw0NMQHoCBXqApBmTZDB4LwcmMJwg0TQobSXToYMmGps6ImZhyXLqoRYABsGoYRrWoDxhCibJg6rKSa67rZrmmD5ksRYlmWFagFWlmqepPGIWKzbREAA)

Comment: That second form is a creative work around, but that cast will look like black magic to almost anyone that stumbles on that snippet.

Comment: Right, so the only way you'd really prefer it is if you happen to have an actual value of that type lying around instead of playing type assertion tricks.